# cloudera distribution of hadoop not getting installed

Tags: unix, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I am installing cdh4 by following the manual given in cloudera installation manual but is not able to install jobtacker, tasktracker using apt-get. Can some one help me out.

```
hduser@Dell:~$ sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Cloudera repository address to your Linux.

For Debian:

> deb http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/-cdh4 contrib
>   deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/-cdh4 contrib

For Ubuntu:

> deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/-cdh4 contrib
>   deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/-cdh4 contrib

Of course, depends on the version of Cloudera that you are planning to use.